# is there a one word synonym for tears in happiness

Tags: word-request, british-english, synonyms

can someone tell me whether there is a one word letter in Britain English for tears which come out in happiness?

It might be of two words also, but do not use 'tears of joy' kind of words..

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that I would use overjoyed or overcome, but I'm fairly sure that there isn't a one-word, or even two-word, synonym for "tears of joy".

Answer (score -1):

I started saying "happy tears" because it sounded cute.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75968)

Comment: @RubioRic This looks like an answer to me. It's bad, however, because it doesn't say whether this expression is actually used in BrE, or whether it's this particular speaker's idiosyncrasy. So there's definitely enough reason to downvote.